# how to get JSON variables from webpage and store them in Java variables

Tags: java, json, selenium, developer-tools

I am making automated tests for a webapplication using Selenium in combination with Java. I arrived at a certain page where I have to get some variables from multiple charts. The problem is: behind the charts the values are not visible in the DOM. This is an
[example of a chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VaLu.png)
and here is the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="bqVisualization: {type:style, data: statistics}, title: displayName" class="">
    <label data-bind="text: displayName">Totaal aantal verzoeken</label>
    <div class="chart"><iframe class="chartjs-hidden-iframe" style="width: 100%; display: block; border: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></iframe>
        <canvas width="500" height="250" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only see a *canvas* in HTML and no variables within the element that I can get for instance using Selenium.

If I look further under *Network* the development tools I find the JSON variables that are used to fill the chart:

```
{
                        "type": "add",
                        "key": "P800-C2-C0-C7",
                        "model": {
                            "key": "P800-C2-C0-C7",
                            "functionalKey": "P800_RapportageAflosvormSpaarrekeningHypotheek_1",
                            "name": "RapportageAflosvormSpaarrekeningHypotheek",
                            "properties": {
                                "value": 18
                            },
                            "children": [

                            ],
                            "displayName": "Spaarrekening",
                            "contentStyle": "statistic",
                            "type": "container",
                            "styles": [

                            ]
                        }
                    }
```

Here is a screenshotview of the JSON variables in [Developer tools -> Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VaLu.png)

So my question is: is it possible to somehow get these JSON variables and store them in Java variables? And if so, where do I start? What tools do I have to use? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: We need to post the call using some client, or Js engine in selenium can do that and store the web response in a string. Then we can parse the string or better convert into JAVA objects using POJO.